# Deselect option before selecting option through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem where I have multiple select buttons in a form and onclick on each button should select different options of the same selectbox.  The below code works fine if I pass a value while onclick but the old value is retained if no value is passed instead of setting it to nul.

Tried formname.reset() before selecting an option to refresh, but this is not selecting any value at all.

For eg, select1 is clicked and first value of select box is selected.  After clicking select2 instead of resetting itself to null, it shows the old value (1).  Select3 works fine again selecting the second value of the select box.

```
    <script>
      function editvalues(arr)
      {
        $('#parent_id option[value='+arr+']').attr('selected','selected');
      }
    </script>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="editvalues(1)">Select1</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="editvalues()">Select2</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="editvalues(2)">Select3</a>

    <select id="parent_id" name="parent_id">
      <option value=''>Select Any</option>
      <option value='1'>First</option>
      <option value='2'>Second</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: this is the kind of thing where a JSfiddle makes solving the problem much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case using `val` method will solve the issue:

```
function editvalues(arr) {
    $('#parent_id').val(arr);
}
```

However you should consider using jQuery *more* rather then old-school inline handlers approach. For example:

```
<a href="#" class="select" data-value="1">Select1</a>
<a href="#" class="select" data-value="">Select2</a>
<a href="#" class="select" data-value="2">Select3</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.select').on('click', function() {
    var val = $(this).data('value');
    $('#parent_id').val(val);
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/iuFEjBKkQZZEpk8keaqx?p=preview

Comment: Had a least expectation that this will work.  Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Glad for your elaborated answer though the earlier did the trick.  The actual code has very tedious loops so i simplified it for better understanding of the question.  Thanks for your response though.  it helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

Se the value to `''` in case no argument is passed.

```
$('#parent_id option[value='+(arr || '')+']').attr('selected','selected');
```

In the above code, `(arr || '')` will return `arr` if it is passed to the function. Else it will return `''` (which happens to be the `value` of the `<option>` that represents no selection).

Comment: The idea is to set it to null before assigning it a new value everytime

Comment: @Majid- You cannot deselect **all options** together. One option has to be selected. From your HTML, it looks like the first option *Select Any* is the one that represents no selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can deselct any selection 1st:

```
function editvalues(arr)
  {
    //deselect 1st
    $("#parent_id option:selected").prop("selected", false)
    //then select passed in value
    $('#parent_id option[value='+arr+']').attr('selected','selected');
  }
```